# Get the link in the href tags

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

how can i get the link in the href tags? How i coded it appears the whole 'a' tag... 
Code:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.meetup.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

categories = soup.find('ul', class_='gridList')

A = []
B = []

for category in categories.findAll('li'):
    text = category.findAll('h4')
    if len(text) != 0:
        A.append(text[0].find(text = True))

for link in categories.findAll('li'):
    url = link.findAll('a', href=True)
    if len(url) != 0:
        B.append(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
(your code above)    
for link in categories.findAll('li'):
    url = link.find('a', href=True)
    if len(url) != 0:
        B.append(url['href'])
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: one moment, will fix

Comment: please check again

Comment: Sure, i just have to wait 5 minutes :D